# laravel @if or @isset show nothing or gives an exeption

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have made in laravel v.8. a database query (eloquent) that returns several columns.

```
$wgName = Auth::user()
            ->join('wg_groups', 'users.wg_group_id', '=', 'wg_groups.id')
            ->get();
```

[image]

Now I want in my html view that the wg_name is displayed if it is set.
I have tried the following four things:

```
@if(isset($wgName->wg_name))

    <h1>{{$wgName->wg_name}}</h1>

@endif
```

Here simply nothing is displayed

```
@if(isset($wgName))

    <h1>{{$wgName->wg_name}}</h1>

@endif
```

Exception: Property [wg_name] does not exist on this collection instance.

```
@isset($wgName)

    <h1>{{$wgName->wg_name}}</h1>

@endisset
```

Exception: Property [wg_name] does not exist on this collection instance.

```
@isset($wgName->wg_name)

    <h1>{{ $wgName->wg_name }}</h1>

@endisset
```

Here simply nothing is displayed

I have no idea why it doesn't work and I didn't find anything in the documentation.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent

Comment: `->get()` returns a collection not a model.

Comment: @gre_gor uff thanks! i changed "get()" with "firstOrFail" now it works like i want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `->get()` on Query builder will give you a Collection instance containing multiple users. And there is definitely no `wg_name` on Collection instance so the result is always false.

Try using `first()`:

```php
$wgName = Auth::user()
            ->join('wg_groups', 'users.wg_group_id', '=', 'wg_groups.id')
            ->first();
```

Comment: Warning, this will always select the first user record, therefor it will give the incorrect result when your system has multiple users.

Comment: @RojVroemen, Sure it is, But I didn't want to change the query. just fixing the error cause.

Comment: This is the query that comes out when querying like that: `select * from users inner join wg_groups on users.wg_group_id = wg_groups.id limit 1`

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are selecting all users from the database. This happens due to Eloquent redirecting non existing methods to a new query builder instance.

By changing the query to use the `first()` method instead of the `get()` method you'll receive only one record, but this would probably not be the correct record as it does not take the current user into account.

There are multiple ways to solve this issue

1: Just use a simple query to receive the `wg_name`.

```php
$wgName = DB::table('wg_groups')->find(Auth::user()->wg_group_id);
```

2: Add a global scope to your `User` model to always join the `wg_group` data when looking up a user.

You could add the following method to your `User` model to always join this table when querying the users table.

```php
protected static function booted()
{
    self::addGlobalScope('include_wg_group', function (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query) {
        $query->join('wg_groups', 'users.wg_group_id', '=', 'wg_groups.id');
    });
}
```

Now everytime you receive an instance of a `User` it will have all the info of `wg_groups` joined into it. This allows you to just grab the name like this:

```php
$wgName = Auth::user()->wg_name;
```